# TS5023: Unknown compiler option 'preserveWhitespaces'

Tags: angular, angular6

I followed the angular 5 to 6 migration guide (https://update.angular.io/). 
One of the things it tells you to do is to set compiler option called `preserveWhitespaces`

I did it for both main `tsconfig.json` as well as `tsconfig.app.json` and both throw `TS5023: Unknown compiler option 'preserveWhitespaces'.` during the compilation.

Comment: Suggested duplicate is not the same as my question. I was getting an error while the duplicate talks about the behavior not working. That said the duplicate did point me to what I was doing wrong. `preserveWhitespaces` goes into the `angularCompilerOptions` NOT `compilerOptions` of `tnsconfig`. I think that's not clear from the angular migration guide and this question should be reopened and properly answered.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this ?  Im getting the same error.